Usar DLL en un script task SSIS
Buen dia comunidad, he desarrollado un código en c#, y quiero usarlo en script task de integration services, pero como no se puede usar librerías externas en ese tipo de componente, quiero hacer referencia a este DLL desde el script task.
Use la opción de Agregar Referencia > Examinar y establecer el DLL mediante la ruta donde se encuentra.
Pero al ejecutar el script task me da el error de que no encuentra el DLL.
Error: No se puede cargar el archivo o ensamblado 'Desencriptar, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ni una de sus dependencias. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

Y todos los DLL que se creó los agregue como referencia.

Como mencioné líneas arriba, intente agregar todas los DLL que se generaron dado que son librerías externas que se usan en el código. Este código al ejecutarlo mediante CMD con el comando dotnet nombre.dll si ejecuta.

[closed] de qué? Si no quieres que te respondan la pregunta, bórrala. Esto no es un foro al uso, cualquier pregunta que dejes hecha se responderá o seguirá por ahí a vueltas

En qué carpeta están esos DLL's? Recuerda que quien va a ejecutarlos es el motor de base de datos, por lo que el usuario que ejecuta el motor debiera tener permisos de lectura y ejecución en dichos archivos.  Por otro lado, has inspeccionado el event log? ¿hay algún dato adicional sobre este error?

He firmado mi DLL y con eso he conseguido que se pueda usar, pero ahora al ejecutar el script task me da un error de que no encuentra la referencia a System.Runtime 8.0.0, pero no estoy usando eso en ningún lado.
